# grep -b -o gives wrong byte-offset with umlaut

Tags: bash, grep

I want to find the right position of the "e" to be able to cut it later. But why does grep return a different output if an umlaut is present before its position?

```
# echo "falle" | egrep -b -o 'e'
4:e
# echo "fälle" | egrep -b -o 'e'
5:e

# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Help would be great !

Comment: Please translate your title to English.

Comment: On my Ubuntu it gives `4:e` for both when I cut and paste your example. (egrep (GNU grep) 2.16)  What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1):

The `-b` option of `egrep` returns the byte offset and not the character offset.
Since your input is `UTF-8` , which is a variable-length encoding, and the ä character is not an standard ASCII character, it uses `2` bytes instead of `1` byte.

That's why the byte offset is `5` instead of `4`.